# Error MSB4018: The "ResolvePackageFileConflicts" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've been trying to build a simple project using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, but always I tried to build project it is showing me following error:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

I try to downgrade SDK version from .net8.0 to .net6.0 but error stills happening.

Comment: hi, I'm afraid that the issue is related to the nuget packages. I think firstly we might try to delete the bin folder in the project file then rebuild the app to see if the issue still existed. If it still existed, we might try to comment the packges one by one to locate the problematic package.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things to check for:

1. Check which version of the Dotnet SDK is actually installed. Try running the following command from the terminal / command prompt:

   dotnet --list-sdks
2. Check to ensure that a supported version of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` is installed as well. EF's "major" version must match the version of `dotnet` you wish to run under. You can run this command to ensure your on the latest version of EF Core that runs under dotnet 6:

   dotnet add Core/Core.csproj package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore --version 6.0.26
3. Also check if your project file is targeting the expected version of dotnet. The project file should have something like this in it:

<ProjectGroup>
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>...

One more note is Microsoft's package versioning typically follows the version of dotnet that they are targeted for.

If your using a 3rd party package, their versioning scheme maybe different than how Microsoft does it now in terms of matching the dotnet version a package is for.

Comment: No, still doesn't work. Aparently error comes from file **Microsoft.NET.ConflictResolution.targets**(40,5), but I don't know what that file does exactly or which information it is trying to get.